# Tinyint MYSQL to true/false string

Tags: php, mysql, typescript, angular, tinyint

I am using `Angular2(typescript)`, `Slim` and `Mysql`.

Mysql can store `boolean` only in `0/1 tinyint`. However [typescript](/questions/tagged/typescript) can't `convert` 1/0 to `boolean`.

Is the best way to convert it intro true/false string before send? Any ideas?

Comment: use a case/when or `if()`

Comment: [Cast it in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php); e.g: `$myBoolean = (bool) $myTinyInt;`. Post an example of your code if you want a more specific example.

Comment: I have a class in typescript with boolean row:
`export class Callback {
  public phone: string;
  public isCalled: boolean;
}`
However mysql store boolean in 1/0. When I get array of Callback angular .json() can't convert 0/1 and true/false as well in boolean field